# LongListSelector: Item tap?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I am using LongListSelector control on Windows Phone 8 and can't figure out the best way to handle a tap on an item.
The few examples I've found rely on the SelectionChanged event. However, this solution is buggy because if I tap an item that opens a new page, hit back, and then tap the same item again, it won't work because this item is already selected, so SelectionChanged is not triggered.

I tried to register to the tap event and use the current selected item as the tapped one, but some times the current selected item is not the one I expect.

I could wrap my ItemTemplate in a button and handle the tap for each item but I need to reskin the button to make it look like a simple list item.

Finally, I don't understand why it is so complicated to achieve such a basic thing. Is there a simple and standard way I missed?

My second wish is to get an effect on the item when it is tapped. Is there any standard way to do it?

Comment: Thanks man for posting such good problem..:)

Comment: good question ,also fit

Comment: Also to get highlighting: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Highlight-a-selected-item-30ced444

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could `null` your LongListSelector's `SelectedItem` at the end of each `SelectionChanged` event. I.e.

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="LLS" SelectionChanged="LLS_SelectionChanged">
```

And the event handler:

```
private void LLS_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {

  // If selected item is null, do nothing
  if (LLS.SelectedItem == null)
    return;

  // Navigate to the next page
  NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/nextpage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

  // Reset selected item to null
  LLS.SelectedItem = null;
}
```

You'll fire the SelectionChanged event twice, but nothing's going to happen the second time round and you should get the behaviour that you're looking for - (i.e Setting `SelectedItem` to `null` will trigger a new `SelectionChanged` event, but this second event gets caught in the if-statement)

As for the second part of your question, you might be better posting a new question.

Comment: Yes, that's what I finaly did. But it seams like a hack for a very usual taks. Don't you think ?

Comment: @Stevie My longlistselector is not firing selectionChanged event either in the viewmodel or code-behind .My long list list selector is in a pivot control and it has a data template . whats the reason

Comment: @Eldho - Without seeing the code it would be impossible to say; I suggest posting a question if you haven't done so already :)

Answer (score 9):

I done it with the **Tap event** handling.

I prefer not to use Selected property, but get tapped item this way (and I haven't noticed any bugs):

```
MyListItemClass item = ((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext 
                                                             as MyListItemClass;
```

Also, you could get the original item ContentPresenter simple by navigating up through VisualTree from e.OriginalSource. That way:

```
ContentPresenter itemPresenter = SomeHelperClass
                              .FindParent<ContentPresenter>(e.OriginalSource,"");
```

Where FindParent is similar to find child in this question: [How can I find WPF controls by name or type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls)

ContentPresenter is that object what you need to manually change the item template if you want to (to set "selected" state for example).

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void Item_tap(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
            DataSource data = (DataSource)element.DataContext;


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> My second wish is to get an effect on the item when it is tapped. Is
>   there any standard way to do it?

For this the only thing you need to do add this to your control (or stackpanel where you want to have this effect):

```
<StackPanel toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
```

Answer (score 0):

first add this to *.xaml page inside the

```
LongListSelectorSelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged"
```

so  that it looks like this :

```
<toolkit:LongListSelector x:Name="listBox" SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged">
```

then in the *.xaml.cs file in the event handler

```
private void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Write your logic on what you want to do with the selected item
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to halil´s answer:

First of all you need to install the Windows Phone Toolkit (WPtoolkit) by NuGet. 
Than add the namespace declaration on the PhoneApplicationPage.

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

After this you can add `toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"` to the control definition.

It is nice documneted by NOKIA:
http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Tilt_Effect_for_Windows_Phone

Oliver