# How to add buttons in longlistselector

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

How to add buttons in LongListSelector?

I have the buttons on the page (When you click navigate to another page)

I need to be in alphabetical order.

Comment: To navigate to other pages. I need to create a longlistselector with item. And to add item click event

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking for. Try to specifiy your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LongListSelector: Item tap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215227/longlistselector-item-tap)